# How to solve the integral equation $f(x) = \int_0^x f(x-y)k(x,y)dy+g(x)$ for $f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, laplace-transform, functional-equations, integral-equations

How do I solve the following integral equation for $f(x)$ given $k(x,y)$ and $g(x)$
$$
f(x) =  \int_0^x f(x-y)k(x,y)dy+g(x).
$$
Any suggestion or reference would be appreciated.

**What I have tried**: I know how to solve the special case where $k(x,y)$ is only a function of $y$. In that case,
$$
f(x) =  \int_0^x f(x-y)k(y)dy+g(x)=(f*k)(x)+g(x)\\\implies F(s) = F(s)K(s)+G(s)\\\implies F(s) = \frac{G(s)}{1-K(s)},
$$
where $F(s)$, $K(s)$, and $G(s)$ are Laplace transforms of $f(x)$, $k(y)$, and $g(x)$. Then we have
$$
f(x) = \mathcal L^{-1}\left\{\frac{G(s)}{1-K(s)}\right\}(x).
$$
I have no, idea what to do with the gerenal case.

**Edit**: Assume $k(x,y)$ and $g(x)$ satisfy any necessary condition for the solution to exist.

Comment: I think in general the function $k(x,x)$ also works and you can write $f(x)*k(x,x)$.

Comment: @MyGlasses I'm not sure I understand your suggestion. For a convolution, shouldn't both functions depend on the integration variable ($y$ in this case)?

Comment: I think in $\int_0^x f(x-y)k(x,y)dy$ $x$ is fixed (say $a$) so we can work with $\int_0^a f(a-y)k(a,y)dy$.